# Only two variables printing after assignment in while loop

Tags: python-2.7

When I run the code, it asks for user input 3 times, but when the conditions are met, it still only prints 2 of them. Why? I am new to Python but have looked around like crazy for any answers on Google but I am still confused.

```
name = raw_input("Name your age: ")
print ("3 choices.")
key = raw_input("What will this world have?: ")

def generator():
   data = 1
   choice1 = ""
   choice2 = ""
   choice3 = ""   
   while(data != 3):
       key = raw_input("What will this world have?: ")  
       data += 1
       if (key == "grass"):
               choice1 = "The world is covered in green grass."
       elif (key == "water"):
               choice2 = "The world is covered in water."
       elif (key == "sky"):
               choice3 = "The sky is vast and beautiful."
       if (data >= 3):   
          print("Before you is " + name)
          print(choice1)
          print(choice2)
          print(choice3)  
          raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
       else:
           print("Invalid Option")


generator()
```

Comment: you increase the `data` count immediately after the user input, regardless if it is a valid option or not. what if you *only* increment the `data` (`data += 1`) inside the `if`/`elif` blocks so that you only count valid `data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes because you start `data` at `1`.
The user then enters their first choice, and you increment `data` to 2.
The user then enters thir second choice, you you increment `data` to 3.

Because `data` is now `3`, it executes your `if data >= 3` statement,
and only prints `choice1` and `choice2` because the user hasn't given their third choice yet.

If you set:

```
data = 0
```

at the start instead of:

```
data = 1
```

Then the user will have to input their third choice and it will work as you expect.

**Update** 
To stop it printing `invalid choice` all the time, you need to move the location of your else from here:

```python
   if (data >= 3):   
      print("Before you is " + name)
      print(choice1)
      print(choice2)
      print(choice3)  
      raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
   else:
       print("Invalid Option")
```

to here:

```python
   if (key == "grass"):
       choice1 = "The world is covered in green grass."
   elif (key == "water"):
       choice2 = "The world is covered in water."
   elif (key == "sky"):
       choice3 = "The sky is vast and beautiful."
   else:
       print("Invalid Option")
```

Otherwise, it will print `Invalid Option` everytime the loop is executed and `data < 3`.

Additionally, if you choose an invalid option, it will mess up your `data` counter. I suggest moving the line that increments `data`:

```python
while(data != 3):
    key = raw_input("What will this world have?: ")  
    if (key == "grass"):
        choice1 = "The world is covered in green grass."
    elif (key == "water"):
        choice2 = "The world is covered in water."
    elif (key == "sky"):
        choice3 = "The sky is vast and beautiful."
    else:
        print("Invalid Option")
        continue # this will skip the rest of the loop if the option is invalid

    data += 1 # only increment if the option in valid
    if (data >= 3):   
       print("Before you is " + name)
       print(choice1)
       print(choice2)
       print(choice3)  
       raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: I tried this in the original code it prompts for all three inputs. When I tried your edit it still says invalid option when I enter the second choice and only prints choice2 and choice3. Any other thoughts? Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: What are you entering when it says `invalid choice`? You might be getting confused with the `key = raw_input` this is outside of the function, it's not doing anything so you should remove it.

Comment: Wow lol ok I removed that and set data like suggested and now it works perfectly! I feel dumb lol thank you! :)

Comment: No worries, check my next edit to fix another bug you'll likely run into. Please consider upvoting my answer if it helped you out.